# How to Preserve last most directory structure when copying files using find

Tags: linux, shell-script

Using "parents" command works but it copies complete directory structure, whereas I need to preseve only the last most directory

```
find /tmp/data/ -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp --parents {} /u01/ABC/ \;
```

Output that I get:

```
/u01/ABC/tmp/data/a/1.txt
/u01/ABC/tmp/data/b/1.txt
/u01/ABC/tmp/data/c/1.txt
```

Output that I need:

```
/u01/ABC/a/1.txt
/u01/ABC/b/1.txt
/u01/ABC/c/1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sh -c` in your `find -exec` command, then you have more control, e.g. to do something like this:

```bsh
find ... -exec sh -c '
    target="/u01/ABC/$(basename "$(dirname "$1")")"
    mkdir -p "$target" && cp --backup "$1" "$target"
' find-sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `cd` into the target directory and run the `find` command from there:

```
cd /tmp/data; find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp --parents {} /u01/ABC/ \;
```

If you need to get back to your original working directory, you can do a `cd -` afterwards or run the command in a subshell:

```
(cd /tmp/data; find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp --parents {} /u01/ABC/ \;)
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for , thanks Freddy !!!